# Abrir fichero con un objeto que almacena otro objeto (wrapper de ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

Buenas, estoy teniendo problemas para poder avanzar con un proyecto, la cuestión es que tengo una clase 'Exposición', la cual a su vez tiene un campo 'Obras' que es un envoltorio de ArrayList.
Cuando guardo mi clase Exposición no salta ningún tipo de error, me genera el archivo aparentemente bien (si añado o elimino contenido y vuelvo a guardar varía el tamaño del archivo). Y cuando vuelvo a abrirlo, aparentemente me abre bien la clase Exposición, pero al revisar el contenido del ArrayList, compruebo que no está cargando los datos que deberían de ese fichero.
Aquí dejo los fragmentos del código, un saludo y gracias de antemano. (Tanto la clase Exposicion como el envoltorio de ArrayList implementan el Serializable

```
public class Exposicion implements Serializable{
    private Obras museo = Obras.getInstance(); // Fondos del museo.
    ...
```

Seleccionando el archivo desde el JFileChooser -->

```
private void abrirFichero() throws FileNotFoundException,
        ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filtro);
    if (fileChooser.showDialog(fileChooser, "Abrir Fichero") == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        Fichero.FICHERO = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        exposicion = (Exposicion) Fichero.abrir(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
        frame.setTitle(Fichero.getFichero().getName());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cargado con exito");
    ....
```

Abriendo el Fichero -->

```
public static Object abrir(File archivo) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo))) {
        return in.readObject();
    }
}
```

EDITO -->
He probado a modificar el campo Obras una vez cargo el fichero, pero de este modo tampoco carga el contenido en el envoltorio:

```
exposicionAux = (Exposicion) Fichero.abrir(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
exposicion = exposicionAux;
exposicion.setMuseo(exposicionAux.getMuseo());
```

SOLUCIONADO  -->

El error estaba en el propio envoltorio de *ArrayList*, pues había declarado a éste como *static*

```
private static ArrayList<ObraDeArte> obras;
```

y los elementos estaticos no pueden ser serializados.

```
private ArrayList <ObraDeArte> obras;
```

Comment: Como le añades datos al Objeto museo, Obras es un singleton?

Comment: Si, Obras es un singleton, para añadir datos despliego una ventana para introducir los campos necesarios de cada elemento. (el arraylist de museo contiene objetos "obrasDeArte") y en el background los añade con arraylist.add(new elementod('campo1','campo2'...));

Answer (score 1):

> Tanto la clase Exposicion como el envoltorio de ArrayList implementan
>   el Serializable

Los elementos que guardes en el ArrayList también han de implementar la clase serializable, o serán ignorados a la hora de guardarlos en un fichero.

Comment: Si, los objetos que guarda el ArrayList implementan Serializable